# Generic Type `toDouble` in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

Hi have the following as bellow.
It is supposed to be a function that calculate the average of a sequence.

```
 def fun1[T <: { def toDouble:Double }] (seq:Seq[T]) = {
    val q2 = seq map { _.toDouble }
    val n = q2.size.toDouble
    q2.sum / n
  }
```

However I cannot pass `Seq(1,2,3)` to `fun1`.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fun1[T <: AnyVal{ def toDouble:Double }] (seq:Seq[T]) = {
  val q2 = seq map { _.toDouble }
  val n = q2.size.toDouble
  q2.sum / n
}

fun1(Seq(1, 2, 3))
```

It seems like the compiler infers the type as AnyRef. Defining it as AnyVal works. AnyRef is the supertype of all objects, while AnyVal is the supertype of all primitives.

Comment: `{ def foo: Foo }` is short for `AnyRef{ def foo: Foo}`. If you want something other than `AnyRef` you have to name it explicitly.

Comment: @sheunis "Seems to work" is a very good way to miss out on the fact that fundamentally `AnyRef` does not include primitive types while `AnyVal` does.

Answer (score 3):

Structural types are very expensive on the JVM and you should avoid them. It stands to reason that only a `Numeric` could be encoded as a `Double`. Scala offers a `Numeric` typeclass as a way to define generic operations on the so called "number types", so you don't actually need to use what you are proposing, the standard lib has you covered.

```
def fun1[T](seq: Seq[T])(ev: Numeric[T]): Double = {
  val q2 = seq map ev.toDouble
  val n = q2.size.toDouble
  q2.sum / n
}
```

You don't really need to get more creative than that if all you want is your operation to be generic on numbers. Otherwise, you will have to implement your own typeclass.

```
trait Converter[T] {
  def toDouble(source: T): Double
}
object Converter {
  implicit def numericConvert[T : Numeric]: Converter[T] = new Converter[T] { def toDouble(source: T): Double = implicitly[Numeric[T]].toDouble(source)}
  implicit object StringConverter extends Converter[String] = ...
}
```

Now to use the simple approach based on `Numeric`, you could define a simple helper.

```
object Helper {
  implicit class ColOps[
    M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X],
    T
  ](val col: M[T])(implicit ev: Numeric[T]) {
    def average: Double = {
      val q2 = col map ev.toDouble
      val n = q2.size.toDouble
      q2.sum / n
    }
  }
}
```

Now all you need to do is:

```
   import Helper._

   List(1, 2, 3).average
   Seq(1, 2, 3).average
   Set(5F, 2F, 3F).average
```

This is a bit more cool, since we can abstract over common collection types too.